# how to set shader to render one object with color and another with texture in dx11?

Tags: c++, shader, directx-11

the tutorial online almost tell us to render object with `color` or `texture`, but no one to tell us if i want one object render with color and another render with texture .like following code

```
    struct VertexIn
{
    float4 Pos  : POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
};

struct VertexOut
{
    float4 Pos  : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
};
```

or

```
struct VS_INPUT
{
    float4 Pos : POSITION;
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct PS_INPUT
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD0;
};
```

so how can i set the struct or `VS` and `PS` function to render one object with color and another with texture ?what's more ,my project is with windows10 sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use "Instance Buffers".  These work along side vertex and index buffers.  You can per object pass not only matrices, but other data such as floats, you can use these to check whether an object should use either colour or texture.  You will need to pass the flag through to the pixel shader, along with the colour and texture coords.  The flag can be as simple as an additional float attached to the instance.

```
struct PS_INPUT
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD0;
    float4 colour : COLOR;
    float4 flags : POSITION1;
};
```

I've used position1 for now, I can't remember the format, but you should use an int rather than float and set it to [nointerpolation], look up the docs.

In your pixel shader, you could then do the following.

```
colourout.rgb = texturesample.rgb * flags.x + colour.rgb * (1 - flags.x);
```

You then just set flags.x in your vertex buffer to 0 or 1 or a combination of the 2.

Comment: in this way means that i need to pass color and texture to every object ?

Comment: Both attributes need to be passed but not necessarily used.   So you could dummy values where you don't use that value.

Comment: @spartawhy117 - if you need help with code samples in regards to setting it all up. let me know.  Can chat offline, and then post the solution here for future reference for all.

Comment: thanks for your help,currently i have finished a simple demo with dx11. my next project is about unity ,maybe i will ask some others question about game development in the future. i hope this site can have feature that can invite special person to answer the question.